# Angular & RxJS - Create Stream using value from another Stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am a bit lost understanding Reactive Programming and merging Streams. Lets supose we have some streams merged in one final stream:

```
 private pageByScroll$ = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
    .map(() => window.scrollY)
    .filter(current => current >=  document.body.clientHeight - window.innerHeight)
    // Solo cuando el usuario para de hacer scroll por 200 ms
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinct()
    .map(y => Math.ceil((y + window.innerHeight) / (this.itemHeight * this.ServicioDatos.elementosPorPagina)));

private pageByResize$ =  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'resize')
    .debounceTime(200)
    .map(_ => Math.ceil(
        (window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop) / (this.itemHeight * this.ServicioDatos.elementosPorPagina)
    ));

private pageByManual$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);

private pageToLoad$ = Observable.merge(this.pageByManual$, this.pageByScroll$, this.pageByResize$)
    .distinct();
```

I took this code from an [example](https://blog.strongbrew.io/infinite-scroll-with-rxjs-and-angular2/) and I am trying to understand it completely, modify and add some more code.

Now I can subscribe `pageToLoad$` to get the page number generated by the merged stream, It runs perfect and gives me the value desired on the time its generated. But I have another method which returns an Observable from the HttpClient which calls to my API Server and gets the results form database. I have been trying to use the values from `pageToLoad$` for sending to the server (nothing works).

This is my api call method:

```
public loadPageOfEmpresas(pageNumber: number): Observable<any> {
    this.loadingMore = true;
    return this.apiService.getEmpresas(
        this.elementosPorPagina + '.' + pageNumber, this.app, 'es', this.latitude, this.longitude, null
    ).map(
        empresa => {
            return this.valueToEmpresa(empresa);
        },
        error => {
            throw new DOMException();
    });
}
```

I supose I need to merge in some way both Observables, but cant get information on how to merge first with his value on the second using the value of the first. Can you tell me which way I have to take and why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why the downvote? What I did wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to call the http service any time the page number changes, i.e. any time `pageToLoad$` emits.

If this is the case, then you may want to try something like

```
pageToLoad$
.switchMap(pageNumber => loadPageOfEmpresas(pageNumber))
```

switchMap is an RxJs operator that basically does the following: any time the source observable emits, in this case `pageToLoad$`, passes the control to the observable that it receives as parameter, in this case the observable returned by `loadPageOfEmpresas`, and completes any previously created observable.

So, if you subscribe to the observable returned by switchMap, than you should have what you are looking for.

You can [read here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-switchmap-operator/) for more details.

By the way, I see that you are passing 2 parameters to the `map` operator, the last being a function to handle error conditions. I think this is not possible. The `map` operator does not accept a second parameter to be a function to handle errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, you are clarifying a lot of concepts. Then if I do `itemResults$ = this.pageToLoad$.switchMap(pageNumber => this.ServicioDatos.loadPageOfEmpresas(pageNumber));` now I could do: `this.itemResults$.subscribe(valuesReceived => {  console.log('Receiving values: ' + JSON.stringify(valuesReceived)); });`?? Thats what I wrote on ngOnInit() function, but it dont works.

Comment: Console.log is never executed on that

Comment: Be careful with using switchMap in this example. It works very well in some specific situations like typeahead search, but you might end up with some very strange bugs. If pageToLoad$ emits on user click, and you care about every request to loadPageOfEmpresas, using switch map is not recommended. You will end up discarding some requests to loadPageOfEmpresas if the used clicks very fast. If you care about every request to loadPageOfEmpresas, you should use mergeMap.

Comment: @TomaszKula thanks. I will search for mergeMap in the documentation in order to see if it arranges it

Comment: Check if `this.pageToLoad$.subscribe(data => console.log(data))` prints anything. If it prints, then see whether there is some activity on the network using chrome devtools.

Comment: The point of mergeMap is correct. It depends on what you to achieve to decide whether to use mergeMap or switchMap. I doubt though this is your problem.

Comment: @Picci `this.pageToLoad$.subscribe(value => console.log(`Valor de pageToLoad$: ${value}`));`Return value = 1. But the suscription of the switchMap (itemResults$) is never executed

Comment: For this to work, your `this.ServicioDatos.loadPageOfEmpresas` must return an Observable. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes Picci. I found an obscured error. I will correct it and test your solution. In any case your answer and TomaszKula are right. Thanks a lot dear friends, you helped me like no one!